# Dependency Injection with ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, modelstate

First, I am aware that using ModelState in a service is typically frowned upon because it tightly couples the service to the Mvc framework. In our case, this isn't a problem, but I do eventually have plans to migrate to an IValidationDictionary and a ModelState wrapper, but need this step to work for now.

Now, on to the issue, this cool guy right here:

```
public class BaseService : IBaseService
    {

      protected MIRTContext _context;
      protected IMapper _mapper;
      //TODO: This tightly couples .NET MVC to our services. 
      // Could be imporoved with an interface and a ModelState wrapper
      // in order to decouple.
      private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

      public BaseService(
        MIRTContext context, 
        IMapper mapper,
        ModelStateDictionary modelState
      ) {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _modelState = modelState;
      }

     async Task<bool> IBaseService.SaveContext() {
        if(_modelState.IsValid) {
          try {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
          }
          catch {
            return false;
          }
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

It keeps giving me this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary' while attempting to activate

I'm assuming I'm missing some sort of AddSingleton thing in my ConfigureServices in Startup.cs but I can't seem to figure out what. Anyone know how to get this to dependency inject properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ModelState` isn't available via Dependency Injection, but you can use [`IActionContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactioncontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which provides access to the current [`ActionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and *its* [`ModelState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.modelstate?view=aspnetcore-2.2) property.

First, you need to register `IActionContextAccessor` for DI:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Next, update your `BaseService` class to use it:

```
public class BaseService : IBaseService
{
    // ...

    private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor;

    public BaseService(
        // ...
        IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor
    ) {
        // ...
        _actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
    }

    async Task<bool> IBaseService.SaveContext() {
        var actionContext = _actionContextAccessor.ActionContext;

        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `actionContext` above will be `null` if the call to `SaveContext` is outside of MVC and its controllers, filters, etc.